# Why are my pytorch vector operations so slow and how can I improve them

Tags: python, performance, pytorch

I implemented my own torch layer, in which I add the values in globs to x according to graph_slices and wrote the following code.

```
# globs.shape = [64, 16]
# x.shape = [4335, 16]
# graph_slices.shape = [65]

for i in range(len(globs)):
    x[graph_slices[i]:graph_slices[i+1]] += globs[i]
```

However, this turns out to be terribly inefficient. Checking with perf_counter() revealed that it takes around 0.003 seconds to run this once, while the rest of my layer which computes presumably much larger matrix operations through torch.nn.Linear layers only takes on the order of 2e-05 seconds. I think it must have to do with my code not really being efficiently parallelized on GPU, but I don't know too many fancy torch functions and can't come up with any solution here.

I am running pytorch 1.10 with cuda and a single gpu.

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: If loop has dependency carriage, it cant be run in parallel, right? When i=0 and i=1 what operations are made? Dooes i=1 access any data written by i=0?

Comment: No, the graph slices array is a monotonically increasing series of integers, so i=0 and i=1 handle different data and there is no dependency carriage. However, I think the way I do it right now, it is not processed in parallel. Do you know any torch trick that would allow parallel processing in this case?

Comment: Are you measuring the timings after synchronizing torch-cuda? I mean, 1 sync after each layer/part to isolate them.